# exit popup with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to exit a popup with JS. I've just followed a tutorial but nothing happens on my popup I'm just thinking if this is a class problem maybe I'm pointing to the wrong class but I've tried everything
i know my pop-up can't work at this moment but i'm at the beginning of my project

here's the link of the tutorial i've followed : https://www.webtips.dev/how-to-make-an-effective-exit-intent-popup-in-javascript

```js
  const exit = (e) => {
      if (e.target.className === "close") {
        // user click on the close button
        document.querySelector(".modal-body").classList.remove("visible");
      }
    };

    document.querySelector(".modal-body").addEventListener("click", exit);
```

```html
<div class="bground">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close"></span>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form
              name="reserve"
              action="index.html"
              method="get"
              onsubmit="return validate();"
            >
              <div
                class="formData">
                <label>Prénom</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="first"
                  name="first"
                  minlength="2"
                /><br>
                <br>
                <input class="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
                <label class="checkbox2-label" for="checkbox2">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Je Je souhaite être prévenu des prochains évènements.
                </label>
                <br>
              </div>
              <input
                class="btn-submit"
                type="submit"
                class="button"
                value="C'est parti"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: would you please tell us more information? which popup? what kind of tutorial? and what have you tried till now? I really doubt that you have tried everything

Comment: 1. there's an error because the function validate doesn't exist . 2. the form submits, so ...

Comment: The HTML code is an openclassroom project and i've to add some JS (i'm a newbie) to this project, so i've followed this tutorial https://www.webtips.dev/how-to-make-an-effective-exit-intent-popup-in-javascript and change things by my class name

Comment: @bravo i didn't call the validate function in my JS and i just want to exit popup when i click i'm at the beginning of the project

Comment: there is no popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element with .close is outside the .modal-body when performing the click event, the supplied event object does not contain the class you are looking for. As a starting point to debug, you can just console.log(e); and see whats in that particular object

Comment: when i just do a console.log(e) it says (modal.js:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined) and here e is just the meaning of event so i don't understant why that doesn't work here too

Comment: Where do you console.log the e? inside the const exit = (e) => { here do console.log(e); }

Comment: my bad i've console.log the e outside the exit const the fact is that now nothing happens, sorry i'm really newbie on JS

Comment: this is what is showing on the console when i click on the exit button   "PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 0, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}"

Comment: And if you inpect the PointerEvent, you see, that there is no "close" in the class list of the target, so this can not work.

Comment: Have a look here. I've added quick something together for you to inspect where to click and then what happens with the .modal-body: https://gist.github.com/lichtwellenreiter/73c250daa9920de1e8b68676865288d2

Comment: path: (8) [span.close, div.content, div.bground, main, body, html, document, Window] in fact the span is showing

Comment: That's working with modal-body but the popup dindn't disapear entirely so i've tried with content but doesn't work

Comment: in fact all the form disapear but the background stay and i've a little black bar staying too 
here's the entire code if u need and want it too :) https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/GameOn-website-FR/

Comment: Have a look here https://gist.github.com/lichtwellenreiter/358ec6530faf5f9dfeebc35abec44256

Comment: Perfect just what i need thanks i was focus on a tutorial who just didn't work for this project or maybe too hard for my case. Anyway thank u !!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong class in eventHandler here:

`document.querySelector(".modal-body").addEventListener("click", exit);`

should be:

`document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", exit);`

Check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hellman-3x9y2s?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Well that's doesn't work in my case... i'm sure this is just a bad call or smth

Comment: It's maybe because your ".close" element is empty. Try <span class="close">Add something here</span> and click on it.

Comment: tried and nothing happens :(